# Write in Excel Apache POI

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

i had created script which get element from excel , .

Here is my script

```
public void readExcel() throws BiffException, IOException {
        String script = "return rlSerial;";
        WebDriver driver;
        String baseUrl;
        System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://website.com/";
        String SiteWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        String FilePath = "D:\\TestData.xls";
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(FilePath);
        Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);

        // TO get the access to the sheet
        Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(0);

        // To get the number of rows present in sheet
        int totalNoOfRows = sh.getRows();
        int totalNoOfCol=sh.getColumns();
        sh.getColumns();

        for (int row =1; row < totalNoOfRows; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < totalNoOfCol; col++){   
                if (col == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Check for Elink "+sh.getCell(col,row).getContents());
                }
                if (col == 1) {
                    driver.get(baseUrl +sh.getCell(col,row).getContents());
                }
                if (col ==2 ) {
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(sh.getCell(col,row).getContents())).click();
                    for (String PromoWindow : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
                        driver.switchTo().window(PromoWindow); // switch focus of WebDriver to the next found window handle (that's your newly opened window)
                    }

                }
                if (col ==3 ) {
                    String exSerial  = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(script);
                    System.out.println("Actual rlSerial = "+ exSerial   + "\t" +"Excpected rlSerial = "+sh.getCell(col,row).getContents());
                    Assert.assertEquals(exSerial ,sh.getCell(col,row).getContents());
                    System.out.println("Pass");
                    driver.close();
                    driver.switchTo().window(SiteWindow);

                }

            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws BiffException, IOException {
        runTest DT = new runTest();
        DT.readExcel();

    }
}
```

If my test cases pass i want to write Pass on next column and if fail then "Fail".

How to achieve this , what to need to be done !!!

Answer (score 0):

To Achieve this first you have to create a new cell in the given row and then set value as "pass" and "fail" to this cell. Use the following code:

```
sheet.getRow(rowNumber).createCell(columnNumber).setCellValue("pass");
```

EDIT:
In your code you are using `Assert.assertEquals(actual, expected)` function which is used with TestNg Annotations, but you are not using TestNG annotations here, So better way is simply compare your actual and expected strings by using `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()` method and set your column pass or fail based on that, Here is the solution you want:

```
if (col ==3 ) {
                String exSerial  = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(script);
                System.out.println("Actual rlSerial = "+ exSerial   + "\t" +"Excpected rlSerial = "+sh.getCell(col,row).getContents());
                //Assert.assertEquals(exSerial ,sh.getCell(col,row).getContents());
                if(exSerial.equals(sh.getCell(col,row).getContents())){
                    sh.getRow(row).createCell(totalNoOfCol).setCellValue("Pass");
                    System.out.println("Pass");
                }
                else{
                    sh.getRow(row).createCell(totalNoOfCol).setCellValue("Fail");
                    System.out.println("Fail");
                }                    
                driver.close();
                driver.switchTo().window(SiteWindow);

            }
```

And save your worksheet after the end of for loop like that:

```
FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File(FilePath ));
    wb.write(outFile);
    outFile.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply , but not getting how to implement , it will be much helpful you one can modify my code , in order to get working .